# How to stop the comma from showing?

Tags: apex

The following code puts a comma in the year. How to get it to stop?

```
    Integer currentYear = System.Today().year() ;    
    Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c=currentYear.format());

    listGoals.add(cpgs);
```

Comment: Is your year__c field a text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()));

listGoals.add(cpgs);
```

Above code works just fine if you're looking for a shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

```
Integer currentYear = System.Today().year() ; 
String strYear = currentYear.format().replace(',','');   
    Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c=strYear);

listGoals.add(cpgs);
```

Comment: Would Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c=String.valueOf(System.Today().year())); be a shorter solution to this?

Comment: of course. just added the line for the ease of readability

Comment: This code also only works if the user's locale happens to use commas. For example, "100.000 00" is a valid locale format, but not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the point @sfdcfox, didn't aware much about locale

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use `currentYear.format()`.

You can directly assign `year__c = String.valueOf(currentYear)`